# Delimiter that accepts numbers in identifiers but not standalone numbers

Tags: java, regex, output, delimiter, identifier

Is there a way to use a delimiter in a manner that will return an identifier, such as name1, but ignore the number 1, in such a way that given "name1 = 1", only name1 will be returned and not 1.  Currently, i'm using .useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z0-9]+").  This allows for the name1 to be returned, but also return all instances of numbers within a given file.  This is being used to build a dictionary of identifiers.

```
while((sourceInput = sourceFile.readLine()) != null){
      String[] dictionaryWords = sourceInput.split("\\W+");
      //ignores white space
      if(sourceInput.equals(""))
        continue;
      if(!sourceInput.contains("//")&&!sourceInput.contains("\"")){//&&!sourceInput.contains(".")){
      for(String dWord: dictionaryWords){
        //replaces periods and commas with blank space, trims white space, and calls toLowerCase
        dWord = dWord.replace(".","");
        dWord = dWord.replace(",","");
        dWord = dWord.trim();
        dWord = dWord.toLowerCase();
        //delimiter call and searches for instances of letters and words
        Scanner remSpace = new Scanner(dWord);
        remSpace.useDelimiter("[a-zA-Z]+\\d+");
        //while loop and successive if loops for creating the dictionary (key, int)
        while(remSpace.hasNext()){
          String resTreeInp = remSpace.next();  
          if(reservedTree.find(resTreeInp) == null){
            if(dictionary.containsKey(resTreeInp)){
            dictionary.put(resTreeInp, (int)dictionary.get(resTreeInp) + 1);//loop to avoid nullPointerException
          }
             else{
               dictionary.put(resTreeInp, 1);
```

Thanks

Comment: It would help if we knew what language you were writing in.

Comment: And .useDelimiter is called on what class instance?

Comment: I'm using it with a scanner, within a loop that ignores white space, anything after "//" comments, anything in quotes.  So, after comparing to a list of reserved terms, I add the unique identifiers (basically anything created by a user) to a dictionary that keeps track of each time the identifier is encountered.  That part of the code is complete. I'm just refining my output to not include stand alone numbers, but to allow for numbers that are included as identifiers, such as an int whose variable name is "name 1".

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are using Scanner? While it is possible to do what you want (I think, something, like `"[\\W\\d]+(?=[A-z])"` should work - it means "at least one non-word character, or a digit, followed by a letter"), it might not be the clearest/most elegant solution. 
Why don't you simply read lines one by one, and then grab your identifiers from them with something like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-z]\\w+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
while(m.find()) { doThisKeyword(m.group(0)); }
```

Edit: also note, that "word character" class normally includes (and "non-word character" excludes) an underscore. So, foo_bar_1 would be a valid keyword in this sense. If you don't want this, replace `\\W` an d `\\w` with `[^A-z\\d]` and  `[A-z\\d]` respectively.

Comment: I'm new to the language and have zero understanding of Pattern or Matcher. I tried the suggested solution (comment) and still am getting stand alone numbers.

Comment: I edited the answer to exclude the standalone numbers, sorry about that. 
This gets hairy though. For example, does an identifier have to only *contain* letters, or does it need to *start* with a letter? The delimiter I suggested does the latter. But, if the line contains something like `1foobar`, it'll skip `1` and return `foobar`.
I doubt that's what you want. 
I'd really recommend you the line-by-line approach, *especially* if you are new and not comfortable with advance regular expressions.
(my solution for line matching also looks for keywords, starting with a letter, but that's easier)

Comment: start, contain, or end would be preferable, at least to make the code robust

Comment: Still returning standalone numbers.  I might just have to accept that for now until I can get a bit more practice.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least one alphabet before the digits. So the regex should be `"[a-zA-Z]+\\d+"`.

Comment: I tried this, but the output still contained the standalone ints used in my variable declaration. For instance, int dog1 = 1 should only return dog1, however, 1 is also being returned.

Comment: That should not be the case. The "+" sign means "at least one occurrence". You can test it out here: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: Its keeping the standalones and ignoring any identifier with a number

Comment: He is using the regexp as a *delimiter* (what to skip), not the pattern to match

Comment: I see. I thought OP's main focus was to return identifiers like "name1", that's why I suggested this regex.